# pandas dataframe to json python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which has 3 series:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import json
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

  df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\xml.xlsx")
  df1['response'] = df1['response'].astype(str)

  tree = ET.parse(df1.response[1]) #This does not work
```

The series in the data frame are:

```
  userid, appid, response
```

The problem that the "response" is a xml document. I need to convert the entire thing into JSON. That means, something like this:

```
  "userid" : "21",
  "appid"  : "40",
  "response" : {"xml document as json"}
```

The step in which I am having problem is to convert the xml into json and then mapping it to the userid.

Sample XML:

```
 <transactionControl>
<userRefNumber>Credit Report Example</userRefNumber>
<subscriber>
    <industryCode>Z</industryCode>
    <memberCode>03919359</memberCode>
    <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>1704</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
</subscriber>
<options>
    <country>us</country>
    <language>en</language>
</options>
<tracking>
    <transactionTimeStamp>2014-08-02T04:27:02.808-05:00</transactionTimeStamp>
</tracking>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need convert `string`s to `json`s by [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html):

```
df1['response'] = df1['response'].astype(str).apply(pd.io.json.loads)
```

Or use:

```
import ast
df1['response'] = df1['response'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: `ValueError: Expected object or value`. I hope you got the problem. `response` contains a big xml document, and I need to convert the entire thing to json like in the example.

Comment: I add another solution for converting, but without data hard answering...

Comment: I edited the question to add the xml. I have posted very little amount of xml. The real data contains a large xml file.

Comment: So problem is not with `json`, but in function `ET.parse`, because data looks like xml, not jsons ?

Comment: Yes bro, it is xml, that's the whole problem. I need to first convert this xml to json then the entire thing with userid and appis into json again to insert this data into mongo

Comment: So it is data related problem, the best is create new question with input all data from `df1.response[1]`, desired output and what you try. Because it is xml parsing problem...

Comment: If it were a xml file then it would have been done. The problem is that I need to link it with the userid and appid. See, this data comes from MySQL which is taken into csv. There are more than a million userids and each has a document like this associated with it.

Comment: @KaranGupta "If it were a xml file then it would have been done" You mean you already  know how to convert an xml file into json?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the xml is in a column and not a file. The ElementTree takes in a document and not a series of a data frame. I need to convert these xml documents and then link them with the userid and appid to create a final json and store in mongo.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here pandas is not helpful, because no native functions for parse `xml`. One possible solution is convert dataframe to `dict`s like `d = df1.to_dict(orient='list')` or maybe `d = df1.to_dict(orient='records')` and then parse `xml`. If want use `pandas` there is solution `df1['response'] = df1['response'].astype(str).apply(func)` and then `def func(x): ` need create function for parsing data. But really hard help more. :(